# How to use observer gem in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

It is the first time to interact with observer gem, and after reading the wiki i just cant get it how would it send a message after creating some record in the database here is the code i used from the git hub wiki with changing the names to an existing model name in my project:

```
  class CommentObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
      def after_save(comment)
        Notifications.comment("admin@do.com", "New comment was posted", comment).deliver
      end
    end
```

i dont know what this function do can anyone please explain it to me as it is not clear in the wiki,Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The `after_save` callback method is overridden to send a email notification. callbacks are methods which are called at specific points(moment) during the creation of an object. so here the `after_save` is called when an Object of type `Comment` is saved. you can read more about callbacks [here](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html).